# Developer sandbox

Tags: php, git, sandbox

I got a rather informative question hopefully not a lame one, as a PHP developer i came across these two terms `sandbox` and `dev box` understand that a sadbox is a developers individual play area '`dev environment`' where developer can write its code without affecting the `integration/staging/production` environments.

**Question 1:**
is the sandbox the same thing as dev box maybe I just heard a different definition of sandbox.

**Question 2:**
How do i create a sandbox for my self, would it be as simple as i.e having my own ubuntu server on a VM or simply my PC, and perhaps commit code to a Integration environment i.e `GIT` where my and colleges commits are managed.

**Question 3:**
Lets say I want my sand box to be on a ubuntu server how I create on and is there anything specific I need to look out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, terminology:

A `dev box` is a specific computer (usually either a PC at the developer's desk, or a server somewhere inside the company's network) on which the developer works. In the former case, these are often differentiated from more "pedestrian" computers used for things like word processing by having more RAM/processor power available, and often having a Unix OS of some kind (either Mac OS X or a Linux flavour) installed rather than Windoze.

A `sandbox` is an environment, often disposable, in which a developer may write code without fear of breaking production/other important environments. A sandbox therefore may reside on a dev box (and most often does), but is not one. The key point is that the sandbox is not connected to production in any way, and can be created, used, and destroyed without affecting other environments (even if those environments run the same code).

As for creating a sandbox for yourself, a complete rundown of your options is quite out of scope for an SO answer. A sandbox can be as simple as a VM on your local machine that hosts your code and any services required to run it, or as complex as you want it to be, with automatic interactions with the rest of your infrastructure to allow pulling/pushing/merging/testing/etc. changes to be easy and seamless.

The only thing I can recommend, really, is to find a workflow that works for you (or whatever is provided by your employer, as the case may be).

Comment: Thank you some much for your answer :) much appreciated